# Cant create iOS ads

Tags: facebook-ios-sdk, facebook-ads-api, facebook-pixel, facebook-events, facebook-ios-sdk-4.0

I am trying to create ads for my iOS and Android application. For this I installed the Facebook SDK, and the events are successfully sent and I am able to see them on events manager as well.

When I try to create ads for my application, when I choose Google Play and my app, everything works fine, I am able to create the. The error happens when I choose my iOS app, I recieve the error:
Sentry (URLParam) threw a restriction on category janky_blackhole_params. See https://www.internalfb.com/intern/wiki/Sentry/FAQ/ TAAL[BLAME_dirs,www/flib/intern/integrity_infra/iop/iaf/,www/flib/integrity_observation/iaf/,www/flib/si/karma/,www/flib/si/sigma/,www/flib/si/sentry/] (#1346003)

What is this error about?

I already tried several times removing and add the app again, but it will show the same error again and again.

What I observed is that, when I click: View the app in the app store link:
https://www.facebook.com/flx/warn/?u=http%3A%2F%2Fitunes.apple.com%2Fapp%2Fid49834258&h=AT0BRaU87cHeW1cqWMOoU9MlRDzWkT8sDV1obMvJBAj9dlSIY6scJ38jNiGUMOE1RH6EkkEXOHA

This link should show my app in the app store is invalid, why?